# How use function in where condition

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want build a query that I need to use **function** in my **where condition**. In this query I want to make a list of those who are late in their payments.

here is my code:

```
$now =Yii::$app->jdate->date('Y/m/d');

$query = ProductUserPayement::find()
      ->where(['<=', ProductUserPayement::dateDiff($now , 'due_date')['days'] , 1]); //for example: where(['<=', 2 , 1])
```

the `dateDiff()` function retruns delayed days in integer and `due_date` is my column in table.

Here is `dateDiff()` function:

```
 public static function dateDiff($date1, $date2){
 $date1=date_create($date1, new \DateTimeZone('Asia/Tehran'));
 $date2=date_create($date2, new \DateTimeZone('Asia/Tehran'));
 $diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);

 $res = [
         'days' => $diff->d, //returns integer
        ];
        return $res;
 }
```

How can I use column name in function?

Let me make an example:

`$now` date is `1401/07/24` and I want chose the rows that pasted this date. In this example the query would be like this:

```
$now = '1401/07/24';

$query = ProductUserPayement::find()
      ->where(['<=', ProductUserPayement::dateDiff($now , 'due_date')['days'] , 1]);
```

With this example the result of `ProductUserPayement` table will be:
[image]

Comment: Unclear what you are trying to achieve. What is your required sql query?

Comment: Please post your table schema, sample data and what you are trying to achieve - a sample result.

Comment: You probably need to write this as SQL function, since `where()` should contain SQL condition and don't accept PHP functions. Something like `where('MY_FUNCTION(NOW(), due_date)' <= 1)`.